# Is there a way to print out a varying number of elements from an array on each line

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to be able to print out a varying number of elements from my array on each line.

```
 String[] name = {"Alix", "Jack", "Alexis", "Adam", "John", "Lexi", 
             "George", "Gregory", "Paul", "Bjorn", "Aaron", "Joseph", "Anderson"};
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
```

The output of this would give me

```
[Alix, Jack, Alexis, Adam, John, Lexi, George, Gregory, Paul, Bjorn, Aaron, Joseph, Anderson]
```

But I want the output to be something along the lines of

```
[Alix, Jack, Alexis]

[Adam, John, Lexi]

[George, Gregory]

[Paul, Bjorn, Aaron, Joseph, Anderson]
```

Is there a way to do this? The number of elements in each line in my example is not set in stone, it's just important that I can vary the amount of names appearing in each line in the output. Thanks

Comment: You can split the Array based on size and then print them.

Comment: Do I need to use an ArrayList to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can split the array manually and use the `copyOfRange` method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String []args){
        String[] name = {"Alix", "Jack", "Alexis", "Adam", "John", "Lexi", 
             "George", "Gregory", "Paul", "Bjorn", "Aaron", "Joseph", "Anderson"};

        int splitArrayForSize = 3; 

        for(int i=0; i< name.length; i+=splitArrayForSize){

            String[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(name, i, 
                                        Math.min(name.length, i + splitArrayForSize));

            String subArrayAsString = Arrays.toString(subArray);
            System.out.println(subArrayAsString);   
        }  
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Alix, Jack, Alexis]
[Adam, John, Lexi]
[George, Gregory, Paul]
[Bjorn, Aaron, Joseph]
[Anderson]
```

I am sure there is a simpler, functional way to achieve this.  I would be interested in that approach.

Comment: @Sid.  You didn't answer the guy's question.  He said that the number of items in each line isn't "set in stone", and in his example, the number of names on each line differs between lines. - Joe got it right!

Comment: @Steve I am OK with any answer accepted as long as it helps.

Comment: We're all using `Arrays.copyOfRange` which @Sid posted first. That's the heart of the solution, the rest is just _"flavours"_

Comment: @Sid, but it doesn't help the community to accept an answer that doesn't give the output you specified, especially once there are others that do.

Comment: @Steve That's what I agreed to.  I am OK with any other answer accepted if it's better.  Remember, it's not me who accepted this answer.  We can urge the OP to accept another better answer.

Comment: @Sid.  Sorry.  I was getting my names mixed up.  I was trying to do just what you say.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that will let you give a list of sizes for each list, so you can easily produce the output you indicate rather than having to have 3 names in each list:

```
package com.inlet.ifserver;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class x {

    public static void main(String ...args) {
        String[] name = {"Alix", "Jack", "Alexis", "Adam", "John", "Lexi",
                "George", "Gregory", "Paul", "Bjorn", "Aaron", "Joseph", "Anderson"};

        int[] counts = { 3, 3, 2 };

        int start = 0;
        for (int count : counts) {
            int end = Integer.min(start + count, name.length);
            if (end == start)
                break;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(name, start, end)));
            start = end;
        }
        if (start < name.length)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(name, start, name.length)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Alix, Jack, Alexis]
[Adam, John, Lexi]
[George, Gregory]
[Paul, Bjorn, Aaron, Joseph, Anderson]
```

Comment: Don't be so quick to upvote and accept answers that don't actually do what you asked (and you can change your mind).

Answer (score 0):

As @Sid mentioned `Arrays.copyOfRange` is the way to go here. This example provides an array of different blocks lengths, so it matches the expected output in your question. It looks like this

```
public static void printInBlocks(String[] arr, int[] blocks) {
    int idx = 0;

    for (int blockSize: blocks) {
        String str = Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(name, idx, idx += blockSize));
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

You can then call it from your `Main` like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] name = {"Alix", "Jack", "Alexis", "Adam", "John", "Lexi",
            "George", "Gregory", "Paul", "Bjorn", "Aaron", "Joseph", "Anderson"};
    int[] blocks = {3, 3, 2, 5};

    printInBlocks(name, blocks);
}
```

The output looks like

```
[Alix, Jack, Alexis]
[Adam, John, Lexi]
[George, Gregory]
[Paul, Bjorn, Aaron, Joseph, Anderson]
```

## Note

The `blocks` which contains the number of items per line needs to have a total sum that's equal to the number of items `name`

Comment: Joe's answer is more robust.  @molamk, I think yours blows up if you don't give just the right numbers in the blocks list.  Joe's will do the best that it can with whatever list it's given, and just ignore group sizes beyond what the input list will allow.

Comment: It is more robust I totally agree with on that. The question is not about "robustness" though. And if it was we would be writing null checks, unit tests and testing for overflows at that point